# namespace name 'MvcSiteMapProvider' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, mvcsitemapprovider

I am getting the following error when I try to run/debug my application

CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvcSiteMapProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

On the following lines of my Web.Config file:

```
Line 179:   <pages>
Line 180:      <namespaces>
Line 181:        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
Line 182:        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
Line 183:      </namespaces>
Line 184:    </pages>
```

As far as I can tell, the reference is present in my project. To make sure I added it from the Nuget Console with:

Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.Web -Project FitAchiever.Web

And it appears to have installed correctly.

If it helps, I have included my web.config here: [My Web Config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12996208/ForumPosts/Web.config)

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Instead of in `system.web`, put the `pages` element inside ` `system.web.webPages.razor`, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [description of the `MvcSiteMapProvider.Web` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.Web/):

> This project contains extra configuration that is required by MvcSiteMapProvider during installation into a Web project as well as a starting point for XML configuration of the provider.
>
> This package is a dependency that is automatically installed with many of the MvcSiteMapProvider packages and you will generally not need to install this package by itself.

In other words, `MvcSiteMapProvider.Web` is not a standalone NuGet package. You must install `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVCx` (where `x` is the MVC version of your project), otherwise the `.dll` is not installed into your project.